# Subir archivos con angularjs en nginx

Tags: nginx, angularjs

Quiero subir un archivo en [angular](/questions/tagged/angular) usando `post multipart`, en el lado del servidor uso [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) como balanceador de carga conectado a varios servidores de aplicaciones y no sé si al hacer esto envíe las diferentes partes del archivo a diferentes servidores de aplicaciones.

Comment: un POST multi-part va en una solicitud única, con separaciones entre las partes, quizá te confundas con un upload en bloques, que si son conexiones por separado. Asi, no hay ningún problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recuerdo en `jquery` haber usado la librería

[jQuery File Upload Angular](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html)

[jQuery File Upload Plugin - AngularJS Fork](https://github.com/DominicBoettger/jQuery-File-Upload)

pero tambien tiene implementacion para `Angular`, como observas hay una directiva que podrías utilizar.

Revisa en la documentación porque menciona a `Nginx`

[Documentation Overview](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki)

Answer (score 2):

La opción recomendada es que uses un plugin

https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

https://github.com/leon/angular-upload

Tambien puedes usar el módulo `$http` para hacer tu petición usando [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) con el pequeño inconveniente que no podrás soportar navegadores viejos ej: IE 8 y 9. Los plugins mencionados anteriormente tienen un soporte para hacer uploads en esos navegadores además de una gran cantidad adicional de funcionalidad por eso te los recomiendo.

Aqui te pongo un ejemplo de como hacerlo usando el módulo `$http`

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('FileUploadController', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.file = '';

      $scope.sendFile = function() {
        $http.post('/api/myurl', $scope.file, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined
          }
        });
      };

    }
  ])
  .directive('fileChanged', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        model: '=',
        prop: '@'
      },
      link: function(scope, element) {
        function changeEvt(evt) {
          var fd = new FormData();
          fd.append(scope.prop || 'myFile', evt.target.files[0]);
          scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.model = fd;
          });

        }

        element.on('change', changeEvt);

        scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
          element.off('change', changeEvt);
        })
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
.boton {
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  color: white;
  background-color: #337AB7;
}
.boton:disabled {
  background-color: lightslategray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="FileUploadController">
  <form ng-submit="sendFile()">
    <div>
      <label for="up">Seleccione un fichero</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="up" type="file" file-changed model="file">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="boton" ng-disabled="!file">Enviar</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Esta es la forma **"angular puro"** de enviar un fichero.

Si te fijas tuve que usar una directiva porque angular no le da soporte a los input de tipo `file` con `ng-model` así que una directiva es la forma de capturar el fichero que se introduce en el input y bindearlo a tu `$scope`. Yo aprovecho y en lugar de bindear el contenido del fichero le pongo ya el objecto `FormData` listo para enviar, ya que `FormData` permite agregar objetos `File` directamente pero esto es sólo uno de los ejemplos de como hacerlo; evidentemente un plugin puede brindarte muchas mas opciones.

Comment: me sirivio tu codigo de angularjs pero como hago para saber que me responde el server ?

Comment: @holamundo Te recomiendo que hagas una pregunta nueva en este sitio ya que eso depende de que tecnología de servidor estás usando.